# How to create installer in different language using Visual C++ (window programming);

Tags: visual-c++, installation

I have a window application in visual c++. I am not using MFC I have to create installer in different languages (French, Italin, German, Dutch, Spanish) can any one help me out in the above task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't create an installer with VC++, you create it with an installer creation tool, such as [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which has multi-lingual support.

Comment: Hi Neil butterworth,
Thanks for you prompt and accurate reply. I have generate the *.iss file can you pls tell me what i have do next to generate the installer.

Comment: If you installed innosetup via its own installer, you should just be able to click on the .iss file to launch the InnoSetup app. Then select Compile from the Build menu.

Comment: Hi Neil Butterworth, I have done that but I have to hand over the installer to the client do the client have to install InnoSet app to install my application

Comment: No, it produces a stand-alone executable in the Output subdirectory.

Comment: Hi Neil Butterworth, Thanks very much for your assistance, the problem is that i am not able to locate the output subdirectory which i think should be in the *.iss dir itself but its not there and have searched the hole system for that but i was not able to find that directory.

Comment: The Output directory should be located in the directory you run the .iss file from. You can change it in the .iss file using the OutputDir directive - look that up in the InnoSetup help. You can change the output file name using the OutputBaseFilename directive.

Answer (score 0):

There are many installers out there:

- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Features)
- [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)
- aforementioned Inno Setup.

You can prepare installation pack for any software. NSIS already has multilanguage support built in, for others - I don't know (didn't use them).